# Squeryl update from select?

Tags: squeryl

Given the following widgets table

```
╔════╦═════════╦═════╗
║ id ║ prev_id ║ foo ║
╠════╬═════════╬═════╣
║  1 ║         ║ bar ║
║  2 ║       1 ║     ║
╚════╩═════════╩═════╝
```

And the following sql query

```
UPDATE widgets 
SET 
  widgets.foo = 
    (
     SELECT widgets.foo
     FROM widgets 
     WHERE widgets.id = 1
    )
WHERE
    widgets.id = 2
```

How do I do the above update in squeryl?

I tried

```
  update(widgets) (
    w=>
      where(w.id === 2)
        set(w.foo := from(widgets)(prevW => where(prevW.id === 1) select foo))
  )
```

But that gave me the following compile error:

```
error: No implicit view available from org.squeryl.Query[Option[String]] => org.squeryl.dsl.ast.TypedExpressionNode[Option[org.squeryl.PrimitiveTypeMode.StringType]].
```

Comment: I'm not sure offhand.  I think you'll have better luck on the Squery list with this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/squeryl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Squeryl added support for sub queries with https://github.com/max-l/Squeryl/commit/e75ddecf4a0855771dd569b4c4df4e23fde2133e

However it needs an aggregate query that is guaranteed to return one result.  This is done with the [compute](http://squeryl.org/group-and-aggregate.html) clause.

I came up with a workaround using compute(min(foo)).

So my solution ends up looking like

```
update(widgets) (
  w=>
    where(w.id === 2)
    set(w.foo := from(widgets)(prevW => where(prevW.id === 1) compute(min(foo))))
)
```

Maybe there should be a `single` aggregate function that throws an exception if the query returns more than one result.

Related conversations:

- https://groups.google.com/d/msg/squeryl/F9JZsPlsjVU/j1FsD7ZDJ08J
- https://groups.google.com/d/msg/squeryl/6ZRMk4I9vZU/CGSiE8q3MpAJ